# Iterating over a parent-less node structure

Tags: java, data-structures, iterator

I have a node structure, **each node have children nodes but no parent node**. I need to iterate over this structure while collecting info to **3 doubles**. Since java have no references I can't use recursion unless I will create a class for these doubles, and also I can't do it without recursion since the nodes are parent-less.

Is there a way to do it in java without changing the structure or creating another class?

The structure:

```
public class Skeleton
{

    public Vector2D head;
    public int numberOfNodes;
    public Skeleton[] nodes;
    public int skeletonSize;
    public Color color;
...
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Showing the actual structure of your nodes would help.

Comment: You could use the Visitor pattern, but this would require adding at least one more class and one more method.

Comment: You can absolutely use recursion in Java.

Comment: "You can absolutely use recursion in Java." - didn't say otherwise..
""java have no references"??" - surprise! you can't pass an int to a function using ref (like in c++ or c#)

Comment: If the nodes are in the `Skeleton[] nodes`, then you can iterate over this array and get the data. What's the real problem?

Comment: @Vladp Java does have references; you are asking for a very specific **kind** of reference. If you want to pass an int by reference, you are free to pass a one-element `int[]`. Second, nothing is ever accomplished in Java without churning out classes. When class is the only tool you have, everything is solved by yet another class. If the explosion of file count bothers you, create `private static` classes, or include several package-private top-level class definitions into one file.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik sorry, I meant the 'ref' syntax from c/c++/c#, but this will do to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you declare:

```
double[] results = new double[3];
```

results will be a pointer to a three element array of doubles. You can pass it around during your recursion, and modify the elements as needed.

However, don't be afraid to create extra classes in Java. You can declare a class inside one of your other classes, for local use.